# python - Can't seem to call a parent class's method from the child

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Here is my code:

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from mutagen import File

class MusicFile:
    """A class representing a particular music file.

    Children that are intended to be instantiated must initialize fields for
    the getters that exist in this class.
    """

    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location

    def getLocation():
        return self.location

    def getArtist():
        return self.artist

    def getAlbum():
        return self.album

    def getTitle():
        return self.title

###############################################################################


class LossyMusicFile(MusicFile):
    """A class representing a lossy music file.

    Contains all functionality required by only lossy music files. To date, that
    is processing bitrates into a standard number and returning format with 
    bitrate.
    """
    def __init__(self, location):
        super().__init__(location)

    def parseBitrate(br):
        """Takes a given precise bitrate value and rounds it to the closest
        standard bitrate.

        Standard bitrate varies by specific filetype and is to be set by the 
        child.
        """
        prevDiff=999999999
        for std in self.bitrates:
            # As we iterate through the ordered list, difference should be 
            # getting smaller and smaller as we tend towards the best rounding
            # value. When the difference gets bigger, we know the previous one
            # was the closest.
            diff = abs(br-std)
            if diff>prevDiff:
                return prev
            prevDiff = diff
            prev = std

    def getFormat():
        """Return the format as a string.

        look like the format name (a class variable in the children), followed 
        by a slash, followed by the bitrate in kbps (an instance variable in the 
        children). a 320kbps mp3 would be 'mp3/320'.
        """
        return self.format + '/' + self.bitrate


###############################################################################

class Mp3File(LossyMusicFile):
    """A class representing an mp3 file."""

    format = "mp3"

    # Threw a large value on the end so parseBitrate() can iterate after the end
    bitrates = (32000, 40000, 48000, 56000, 64000, 80000, 96000, 112000, 
                128000, 160000, 192000, 224000, 256000, 320000, 999999)

    def __init__(self, location):
        super().__init__(location)

        id3Info = EasyID3(location)
        self.artist = id3Info['artist'][0]
        self.album = id3Info['album'][0]
        self.title = id3Info['title'][0]
        # Once we set it here, bitrate shall be known in kbps
        self.bitrate = (self.parseBitrate(File(location).info.bitrate))/1000
```

Now, when I try to instantiate an `Mp3File`, it gives me an error on the last line of `Mp3File.__init__()`:

```
line 113, in __init__
self.bitrate = (self.parseBitrate(File(location).info.bitrate))/1000
NameError: name 'parseBitrate' is not defined
```

However, it seems to me that it should be failing to find the method in `Mp3File`, and then looking for the method in the parent class, `LossyMusicFile`, where it does exist.

I tried changing that line to `self.bitrate = (super().parseBitrate(File(location).info.bitrate))/1000` so that it would be explicitly using the parent class's method, but I get the same error. What's going on?

Apologies if this has been asked before or is a dumb question, but I couldn't find it when I searched and I am, in fact, dumb.

Comment: All of your instance methods **must** have `self` as the first parameter.

Comment: See my updated answer...

Comment: With my crystal ball I can tel you are running Python 2....

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I'm definitely trying to use python 3. What am I doing python 2-like that should be different for python 3?

Comment: @lucas755 whether it's python 2 or python 3 you should inherit off of object in  `MusicFile`.  this will fix your problem in python 2 but you wouldn't have this problem in python 3 because in python 3 everything inherits off of object, but for compaitability reasons, you should still inherit off of object

Comment: please click the checkmark below the vote counter to accept my answer and/or upvote my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Don't worry, I was getting to it. Just had to implement your solution and see that everything worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your instance methods must have self as the first parameter. What's happening here is that in `parseBitrate()` you renamed `self` to `br`. You need `parseBitrate(self, br)` in order to accept a bitrate. You need to add `self` to the argument list in other methods like `getFormat()` too.

1. Your code uses `thisVariableNamingStyle` it's against Python's offical style document, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
2. `MusicFile` doesn't inherit off of `object`. **You can only call methods inherited from a a higher class in "new-style classes".** In order to make your class "new-style", you must inherit off of `object`.

In addition, get an IDE like PyCharm that can automatically warn you of these errors in the future.

Comment: This is Python 3.x so inheritance from `object` is built in.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. I haven't picked up python in a while since working on a project in Java. It seems I picked up some bad habits!

Comment: @lucas755 PyCharm is free, btw